# some columns in DataFrame is Nan ,python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new with python ,I extracted data from twitter and I want to put them in DataFrame .

so I wrote this line of code:

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets],columns=['tweets'])
```

and I tried to add more columns using this code:

```
import numpy as np


data['len'] = np.array([len(tweet.text)for tweet in tweets])
data['ID'] = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
```

but an error appears:

> Length of values does not match length of index ,

even the length is equal and I checked it using `sum()` method. I searched and found some solutions which use `concat()` method and it works but when I print the dataframe the len and ID is Nan 
so I checked that by putting print stament in the loop

```
 for tweet in tweets:
    print(len(tweet.text))
    print(tweet.id)
```

and it is contain value not `Nan`

so what is the problem and how can i solve it?

Comment: check `len(data)` and `len(np.array([len(tweet.text)for tweet in tweets]))` and `len(np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets]))`

Comment: len(data) is 400 and len(np.array([len(tweet.text)for tweet in tweets])) and len(np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])) are 0, even when i writ for tweet in tweets:
    print(len(tweet.text))
    print(tweet.id)     are contain values so the length mustn't be 0

Comment: That should work, so the problem isn't likely in the few lines you posted. Maybe you updated `tweets` between the time you first created your dataframe and then tried to add more columns.